# increment button starting from zero instead of one

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote the code to display 0 until the increment button is clicked but it starts from one.

```js
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el")
console.log(countEl)

let count = 0;

function peopleEntered() {
  count = count + 1;
  countEl.innerText = count;
  console.log(count);
}
peopleEntered();
```

```html
<div class="countapp">
  <h1>People Entered: </h1>
  <h2 id="count-el">0 </h2>
  <button type="button" id="increment-btn" onclick="peopleEntered()"> INCREMENT </button>
  <script src="index.js">
  </script>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Don't call `peopleEntered()` in js or init from `-1`

Comment: Thanks it worked after i removed the the peopleEntered() in js

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking `peopleEntered()` in your JS file, causing it to be invoked right when the script gets loaded, meaning that the count will get increased by one at the start. Just remove the invocation, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thanks working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Do not call your `peopleEntered` function, unless you click the button.

```js
const countEl = document.getElementById("count-el");
console.log(countEl);

let count = 0;

function peopleEntered() {
  count += 1;
  countEl.textContent = count;
  console.log(count);
}
```

```html
<div class="countapp">
  <h1>People Entered:</h1>
  <h2 id="count-el">0</h2>
  <button type="button" id="increment-btn" onclick="peopleEntered()">INCREMENT</button>
</div>
```